# Sort dataframes by iloc method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to sort the column which is present before the column contains keyword "DE Call". I have 3 dataframes, can I do this in for loop?
It is in the dictionary now. I want to sort column: x vs m (by mentioning the column before DE call)

```
Input: 
{0:
Probe Name   Acc            x vs m                DE Call of x vs m                   
 ABL1        NM_005157.3    0                     mRNA   
 ACVR1B      NM_004302.3    1                     mRNA  
1:
Probe Name   Acc            x vs m                DE Call of x vs m                   
 ABL1565     NM_005157.3    6                     mRNA   
 ACVR1B      NM_004302.3    0                     mRNA  
2:
Probe Name   Acc            x vs m                DE Call of x vs m                   
 ABL1868     NM_005157.3    8                     mRNA   
 ACVR1B      NM_004302.3    1                     mRNA }

Expected O/P: 
{0:
Probe Name   Acc            x vs m                DE Call of x vs m                   
 ABL1        NM_005157.3    0                     mRNA   
 ACVR1B      NM_004302.3    1                     mRNA  
1:
Probe Name   Acc            x vs m                DE Call of x vs m                   
 ACVR1B      NM_004302.3    0                     mRNA
 ABL1565     NM_005157.3    6                     mRNA   
2:
Probe Name   Acc            x vs m                DE Call of x vs m                   
 ACVR1B      NM_004302.3    1                     mRNA
 ABL1868     NM_005157.3    8                     mRNA   }
```

Comment: Please provide a dummy dataframe and an expected output.

Comment: I have edited the question with I/p and o/p

Answer (score 1):

I let three df as df1, df2, df3.

```
for df in (df1, df2, df3):
    column_list = df.columns.values.tolist()
    DE_index = 0
    for index in range(len(column_list)):
        if column_list[index].startswith('DE Call'):
            DE_index = index
            break

    col_to_sort = column_list[DE_index - 1]

    df = df.sort_values([col_to_sort])
    #print(df)
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. Have one doubt,

res=pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name=sheet1)
for res in (FC_filter1,FC_filter2,FC_filter3):
    column_list = res.columns.values.tolist()
    DE_index = 0
    for index in range(len(column_list)):
        if column_list[index].startswith('DE Call'):
            DE_index = index
            break

    col_to_sort = column_list[DE_index - 1]

    print(res.sort_values([col_to_sort]))

Is this any way to avoid manually typing FC_filter1,2,3?

Comment: If FC_filter 1, 2, 3 are the ones you want to deal with, then you can just put them like the code. As I don't know how the dataframe exists, I just assigned the variable names df1, df2, df3 and put them in to tuple cuz you wanted it in for loop.

Comment: `res = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet1)` means that `res` is a DataFrame. In the code `for res in (FC_filter1, FC_filter2, FC_filter3)`, res is a DataFrame one of them(tuple). I think you should handle it.